# Show metric is not only a metric, but an equivalent metric on $X$

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces, solution-verification

> Let $\left(X,d_1\right)$ and $\left(Y,d_2\right)$ be metric spaces and let $f\colon X\to Y$ be a continuous function. Show that $\rho(x,y):=d_1(x,y)+d_2(f(x),f(y))$ is a metric on $X$ equivalent to $d_1$.

To show $\rho$ is a metric on $X$:

Notice for any $x,y\in X$, $d_1(x,y)\geq0$ and $d_2(f(x),f(y))\geq0$ as $d_1$ and $d_2$ are both metrics, so being the sum of two non-negative numbers $\rho(x,y)\geq0$.

Further for any $x,y\in X$, $d_1(x,y)=d_1(y,x)$ and $d_2(f(x),f(y))=d_2(f(y),f(x))$ as $d_1$ and $d_2$ are both metrics, so being the sum $\rho(x,y)=\rho(y,x)$.

Suppose $\rho(x,y)=0$ for $x,y\in X$, that is $d_1(x,y)+d_2(f(x),f(y))=0$. This occurs iff both $d_1(x,y)=0$ and $d_2(f(x),f(y))=0$. This occurs iff $x=y$ and $f(x)=f(y)$. In other words, $\rho(x,y)=0$ for $x,y\in X$ iff $x=y$.

For $x,y,z\in X$, $d_1(x,z)\leq d_1(x,y)+d_1(y,z)$ and $d_2(f(x),f(z))\leq d_2(f(x),f(y))+d_2(f(y),f(z))$ as $d_1$ and $d_2$ are both metrics, so being the sum
$$\rho(x,z)\leq d_1(x,y)+d_1(y,z) + d_2(f(x),f(y))+d_2(f(y),f(z)),$$
that is $\rho(x,z)\leq \rho(x,y)+\rho(y,z)$.

To show $\rho$ is an equivalent metric to $d_1$ on $X$:

Consider the identify mapping $\text{id}\colon\left(X,\rho\right)\to\left(X,d_1\right)$. For every $\varepsilon>0$ there exists a $\delta:=\varepsilon>0$ such that when $\rho(x,y)<\delta=\varepsilon$,
$$d_1(\text{id}(x),\text{id}(y))=d_1(x,y)\leq\rho(x,y)<\varepsilon$$
that is the identify mapping $\text{id}\colon\left(X,\rho\right)\to\left(X,d_1\right)$ is continuous.

Now consider the identify mapping $\text{id}\colon\left(X,d_1\right)\to\left(X,\rho\right)$. Since $f$ is continuous, for any $x\in X$ there exists a $\delta\in(0,\varepsilon/2)$ such that when $d_1(x,y)<\delta$
$$d_2(f(x),f(y))<\varepsilon/2.$$
But then
$$\rho(x,y):=d_1(x,y)+d_2(f(x),f(y))<\delta+\varepsilon/2<\varepsilon/2+\varepsilon/2,$$
that is the identify mapping $\text{id}\colon\left(X,d_1\right)\to\left(X,\rho\right)$ is continuous.

Therefore, $\text{id}\colon\left(X,\rho\right)\to\left(X,d_1\right)$ is a homeomorphism so $\rho$ is an equivalent metric to $d_1$ on $X$.

---

My question is rathe simple, is the above correct? If not can it be correct?

Comment: Looks good to me.

Comment: Yes. It's fine. You can also do it by using the fact that two metrics are  equivalent iff they have the same convergent sequences.... An application: A non-compact metric space $(X,d)$ has an equivalent unbounded metric: First show that $X$ has a closed discrete subspace $\{x_n: n\in \Bbb N\}$ with $m\ne n\implies x_m\ne x_n.$ Second, show there is  a continuous $f:X\to\Bbb R$ with $f(x_n)=n$ for each $n$. Third, let $e(x,y)=d(x,y)+|f(x)-f(y)|.$